# Axios get request not working properly, what do I do?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, axios, get, react-query

So I have this project where I have to make a store management React app where you have

- Products
- Sections
- Racks (a rack is a spot in a section where a product can be placed)

So these racks are placed in a Floorplan component where I loop over the Racks in a specific Section. This is working properly as you can see in next screenshot.
[image: This is a console.log for all the racks that are in this section]

When I go further and I .map the 'racks' result, I'm trying to fill each rack with a product, by calling  with the right data to fetch the product that has to be placed there.

```
<div className="floorplanWrapper">
    {racks.map(({id, productId, sectionId, col, row}) => {
        if (productId === null){
            return<div key={id} style={{position: "absolute" , top: col, left: row}}>
                    No product specified
                    </div>
        }
        else {
            return <RackItem key={id} productId={productId} sectionId={sectionId} row={row}  col={col}/>
        }
    })}

</div>
```

So I pass the productId to the RackItem, in Rackitem I do a call to get the right product by the specified productId.
Like following -> (ignore the simplicity of using the product, at this moment i'm just trying to access the data and not layout the page.

```
export function RackItem({ sectionId, productId, col, row }: RackItemProps) {
    
    const {isLoading, isError, product} = useProductItem(productId);

    
    if (isLoading) {
        return (
            <CircularProgress sx={{display: "block", mt: "10em", mx: "auto"}}/>
        );
    }

    if (isError || !product) {
        return <Alert severity="error">Product could not be loaded</Alert>;
    }

    return (
        <>
            <div> {product.name}</div>
        </>
    )

}
```

the function useProductItem is the following ->

```
export function useProductItem(id: string) {
    const {
        isLoading,
        isError,
        data: product,
    } =  useQuery(["products"], () => getProduct(id));


    return {
        isLoading,
        isError,
        product,
    };
}
```

the function getProduct(id) is the following ->

```
export const getProduct = async (id: string) => {
    const product = await axios.get<Product>(`/products/${id}`);
    return product.data;
};
```

So I expect a different product each time I make a component 'RackItem', but for some reason it only gives me the product with id: 1.

[image: the page for floorplan where i place the rackitems]

Can anybody tell me why the axios request returns the same object every time?
If you need more code or pictures you can ask me.

I tried removing async and await, but no success.

Answer (score 2):

Your query key does not vary:

```
useQuery(["products"], () => getProduct(id));
```

So you are likely getting the cached result every time:

```
useQuery(["products", id], () => getProduct(id));
```

Comment: query returns one item, so the key can not be plural

Comment: The key can be whatever convention you want - if your endpoints are `/api/blogs/:id` it may be perfectly fine to use `blogs`